# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key

I totally confused, because I have mistake in my console and I read reactjs documentation and all tips on stackoverflow, but I can't unterstand what problem is.
I see list of book's titles ({item.volumeInfo.title}), but console has error.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class BookList extends Component {
    renderBook(mainData) {
        return(
             <ul>
                {mainData.items.map((item, i) => {
                    return <li key={i} item={item}>{item.volumeInfo.title}</li>
                    })}
             </ul>
        )
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="book-row">
                <div className="book-info">
                    {this.props.book.map(this.renderBook)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({book}) {
    return {book};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

It is part of API response:

```
{ "kind": "books#volumes", 
 "totalItems": 288, 
 "items": [ 
  {
   "kind": "books#volume",
   "id": "yXlOAQAAQBAJ",
   "etag": "CG7f2mQ+7Nk",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/yXlOAQAAQBAJ",
   "volumeInfo": {
    "title": "Nineteenth Century Home Architecture of Iowa City",
    "subtitle": "A Silver Anniversary Edition"
```

I tried to do the next keys:

**key={item.etag}, key={i}, key={item.volumeInfo.title}**

but error is still here.

Please help.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are mapping over `book`:

```
{this.props.book.map(this.renderBook)}
```

the `ul` also needs a `key` prop:

```
renderBook(mainData, bookIdx) {
        return(
             <ul key={bookIdx}>
                {mainData.items.map((item, i) => {
                    return <li key={i} item={item}>{item.volumeInfo.title}</li>
                    })}
             </ul>
        )
    }
```

This is because there will be many `ul` siblings and React needs to tell the difference (same as with `li`).

However, it is better (if possible) to use a key that is not the index of the array.  So, if `book` and `item` have a unique identifier, it would be best to use that.

So, it looks like you have another array outside of the sample data you provided:

```
[
 { "kind": "books#volumes", 
   "totalItems": 288, 
   "items": [ 
    {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working! 
I totally agree with using data from array, I will use key from it.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are using two `map`, and assigning the `key` in only one, assign the `key` to `<ul>` also, because of that it is giving you the error, Try this:

```
renderBook(mainData, index) {
    return(
        <ul key={index}>
            {mainData.items.map((item, i) => {
                 return <li key={i} item={item}>{item.volumeInfo.title}</li>
             })}
        </ul>
      )
}
```