# How to use setState in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use setState in map function
what I want to make when I hit click button that makes states changed

I searched "In map function changed setState" in stackoverflow

but It was hard to understand..and apply my case

```js
this.state = {
      categories: [
        {
          category: 'sports',
          ariticles: [],
          isClick: true
        },

...
...

 return (
      <div>
        <hr></hr>

        <div className="categoryBtn">
          {this.state.map(item => (
            <button
              onClick={
                () => this.setState(() => (item.isClick = false))
                // () => console.log((item.isClick = false))
                // this.setState(() => (item.isClick = !item.isClick))
              }
            >
              {' '}
              {item.category}
            </button>
          ))}
```

when I hit my button I got error ' this.state.map is not a function'

I expect when I hit button, isClick will be toggle

Comment: .map is only available in an iterable, your `this.state` is an object, i think you need to refer `categories` array. so it should be `this.state.categories.map(...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `this.state` refers to an object containing an array,

```
categories: [...]
```

So you'd need to map over `this.state.categories.map` instead of `this.state.map`

---

And also, I've noticed that `button` event handler mutates the state.

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState(() => (item.isClick = false))}>
  {item.category}
</button>
```

You'd need to return a new item `reference` to notify react that the state has been changed as well as adding a `key` prop.

*Thankfully, someone asked a question about the reason for using key (only 2 hours ago) and replied, which you can refer to.*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57838612/4035

```
<button key={item.category} onClick={() => this.setState({
    find the item by searching for each item in `this.state.cateogies`
  })}>
  {item.category}
</button>;
```

But then it gets tough to find the right element, so I'd recommend to normalize(meaning change the `this.state.categories`) too look like following for easier way to set the state.

```
// From this
this.state = {
  categories: [
    {
      category: "sports",
      ariticles: [],
      isClick: true
    },
    {
      category: "sports",
      ariticles: [],
      isClick: true
    }
  ]
};

// to this
this.state = {
  categories: {
    sports: {
      category: 'sports',
      ariticles: [],
      isClick: true
    },
    news: {
      category: 'news',
      ariticles: [],
      isClick: true
    }
  }
};
```

This way, you can set the state like following.

```
<button
  key={item.category}
  onClick={() =>
    this.setState({
      [item.category]: {
        isClick: false
      }
    })
  }
>
  {item.category}
</button>
```

---

Reply to the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839029/how-to-use-setstate-in-map-function/57839043#comment102107434_57839043) (I've translated the comment for non-Korean speakers)

> So you can't use `.map` any more after making such a change?

I am sorry, I should've updated the category item generation code after the state update.

No, you can't use `.map` as it's now an object. But thankfully, you can use either `Object.keys/value/entries` to iterate the `this.state.categories`.

*You can click on "Run code snippet" button to see the output*

```js
let state = {
  categories: {
    sports: {
      category: "sports",
      ariticles: [],
      isClick: true
    },
    news: {
      category: "news",
      ariticles: [],
      isClick: true
    }
  }
};

Object.entries(state.categories).map(([id, item]) => console.log(item))
```

So your code would look like something like,

```
<div className="categoryBtn">
  {Object.entries(state.categories).map(([id, item]) => (
    <button
      key={id}
      onClick={() =>
        this.setState({
          [item.category]: {
            isClick: false
          }
        })
      }
    >
      {item.category}
    </button>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: 친절한 답변 감사드립니다 @Sung M. Kim

Comment: 근데 위와 같이 바꾼다면 map을 쓸 수 없는거 아닌가요..?@Sung M. Kim

Comment: @youngban `this.state.categories`는 이제 object이라서 map은 못쓰시구요, `Object.entries/value/keys`를 사용 하시면 됩니다. 제 위에있는 대답을 참고 해주세요.

Comment: 감사합니다! 다시해보겠습니다 @Sung M. Kim

Answer (score 2):

Try this :::

```
{this.state.categories.map(item => ( ..... ))}
```

Comment: Nothing new compared to the already existing answer. No effort to provide some explaination why the code did not work and this one should.

Comment: I believe I typed a bit faster than he did. But as @Mariselvam is a new contributor, thank you for replying to the answer. You could try to provide more thorought answer next time and here is my +1  for {...}